# abandon part of a bash script if the time is later than 6am

Tags: bash, time

We have a bash script that runs a set of other stuff, each of which takes a variable amount of time to run. If we get to 6am and it hasn't finished, then we want to abandon the rest of the script.

How do we test the time inside the bash script and then abandon the script if it's gone over a certain time of day?

Answer (score 4):

Use this condition:

```
[ $(date "+%H%M") -gt 600 ] && {
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know, just in case he wanted to add more commands. It's better than doing `[ -condition ] && command && command && command`

Comment: Wouldn't an `if` statement be clearer?  (Hint: Yes, it would.)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I've now implemented the solution.